# How can I filter a table using an aggregate condition?

Tags: sql, having

I have a simple table of 10 customers with ID, Name and Age.
How can I filter this so that I only select Customers with Age > 30?
I tried the HAVING clause but keep running into problems.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code below:
My Code below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer_Table
HAVING Age > AVG(AGE)
```

Comment: You could use a sub query `where age > ( select AVG(age) from Customer_Table)`

Comment: `having` is for aggregation, which you aren't doing - use a sub query or analytic `over()`

Comment: Which do you want: customers older than the AVG(Age) or older than 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer_Table
GROUP BY Age
HAVING Age > (SELECT avg(Age) from Customer_Table)
ORDER BY Age desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be

```
select <columns> from (
  select *, avg(age) over() AvgAge
  from Customer_Table
)t
where age > AvgAge;
```